# Take filenames from folder starts from the second file instead from the first

Tags: excel, vba, get, filenames

this is my vba script:

```
Sub ListAllFiles()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        selectDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
        dFileList = Dir(selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
    
        Do Until dFileList = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(nextRow, 1) = dFileList
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
            dFileList = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I currently don't understand why if the folder contain 20 files.
The script is starting to take file names from the 2th file until reach the last one and the first file is always skipped.

I try to switch from:

```
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
        dFileList = Dir
```

to:

```
        dFileList = Dir
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
```

but this doesn't make any change.
Also try to change from **SelectedItem(1)** to **SelectedItem(0)** but I receive error.
The next thing I try to change from **Cells(nextRow, 1) = dFileList** to **Cells(nextRow, 0) = dFileList**

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I was added right before **Do Until**

```
nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0
```

but if I want to get all files again without to delete the existing filenames in the column A
 I was overwrites the last one cell.
The solution is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks to be the next code line:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

It is useless in the context of your code.

It only **does not let you see that, first time, `Cells(nextRow, 1) = dFileList` returns an error**, since `nextRow = 0`.
And your iteration continues only for the second file, when `nextRow` is already 1, returning a correct range...

In order to check that, try inserting `Debug.Print dFileList` before `On Error Resume Next`. You will also see in `Immediate Window` (Being in VBE - `Ctrl + G`) the first file name, too.

Try using `nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Your way (`nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0`) made the code return all the file names, but it overwrites the last existing value on A:A column...